# SharePoint 2010 REST service: Getting a users quicklinks

Tags: sharepoint-2010

On a standard SP 2010 server, I want to get the currents users quicklinks using REST.  I've tried calls such as http://localhost/my/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/QuickLinks without success (404 Not Found).

I have the feeling that the quicklinks aren't stored in the users mysite but somewhere else. 
Does anybody know how to retrieve the current users quicklinks using the SP REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is not stored in a SharePoint list, you cannot access it via the REST APIs. I'm pretty sure user quick links fall into the category of data that is not stored in a list.